# Checking the value of a multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I am using a multiselect which is created in such fashion

```
var color = $('<select />', {
                              'id'     : 'color_' + j,
                              'name'   : 'color_'+ j+'[]',
                              'multiple': true,
                              'style' : 'float: left; width: 120px; position: relative'
                            }).attr('data-rel', 'chosen');
```

Now within a javascript when i am alerting the value of the multiselect with id = color_1
i am getting null

I mean for the script

```
for(i = 1; i<=ci; i++)
 {
    alert($('#color_'+i).val());
    if($('#color_'+i).val() == 'null' || $('#color_'+i).val() == '')
    {
       alert("Select Color For Item :"+ (i));
       flag = 1;
    } 
 }
```

`null` is getting alert if i dont select anything, but still, its not alerting the `alert("Select Color For Item :"+ (i));`

if `alert($('#color_'+i).val());` is causing null to be alerted, then it must enter into the if condition, but it seems somehow the if is not getting satisfied.

Can anybody help me in this?

Thanks.

Comment: can you create a JSFiddle

Comment: Aah!! i was so idiotic to get this simple thing into my head... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you are comparing against a string `'null'` where as you should be checking it against the `null` value

```
var val;
for (var i = 1; i <= ci; i++) {
    val = $('#color_' + i).val()
    alert(val);
    if (val == null || val == '') {
        alert("Select Color For Item :" + (i));
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```